# Recreate a uitableview section dynamically on a uibutton`s click

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I need to recreate a UITableView section on a UIButton click. Here is an example for this.

[image]

AND in button click it should be created like this.

[image]

But i am not able to implement this .

Please Help.
I am just creating a simple UITableView with a textLabel.

Code For cellForRowAtIndexPath is

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Please help me with this, do you want to create a new row when user click on plus button or a separate new Table view? If yes where you are planning to add that, since you already have one table view on screen.

Comment: What is the method that is called on the button's touchUpInside event?

Comment: @ Parvez Belim - I need to recreate all the rows of the uitableview may be in a new section every type uiButton is clicked

Comment: @ ZeMoon- On UIButtons Action i want to create a new section which repeates all the row items of the previous section.

Comment: I recommend create new Section for the existing tableview rather than create a new table view. Increment the roof section, and do the changes in your model and reload tableview

Comment: @ jpulikkottil - Thanks for you suggestion , Please help me with code , As Not able to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a integer variable `index` and property for tableview in .h

```
@property UITableView *tableView;
```

Then in `-(void)viewDidLoad` set `index=0;`

Now, write a method which is get called when you tap on add button

```
-(void)newTableView
{
tableView = [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y+height*index,width,height)]; 
//other code related to table
tableView.tag = ++index;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

> Use tag in delegate methods

**Edit:** As you requested to add new section in Table View instead of new table view
You have to first create table view of grouped style

```
tableView = [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Now, When you hit on that add button call a method

```
-(void)newSection
{
  count++;
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Then, you have to implement this delegate methods for grouped table view

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"title";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   //same as your previous code
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //same as your previous code
}
```

Comment: Lalit Kumar - Dont want to create a table every time , I want to create  a section

Comment: are you creating group tableview?

Comment: you have to reload tableview every time when click on add button

Comment: No, Its simple UItableVIew @ Lalil Kumar

Comment: so, simple UITableView has only one section, you need to create your tableview grouped

Comment: Ok , What To do know ??

Comment: `[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`

Comment: are you using `[self.view addSubview:tableView];`

Comment: you also have to change frame dynamically?

Comment: Thanks bro , just one more thing, i have that UIbutton in UItableview footer. I wanted to show that footer in end only ,But now it is appering at every section

Comment: you can use  `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(section is last) return footer; 
else
return nil;
}`

Comment: or you use another approach to add button

Answer (score 1):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  DynamicNewSections
//
//  Created by J Pulikkottil on 14/07/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 J Pulikkottil. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewTest;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.arrayData = [NSMutableArray array];


//section1
[self addSectionArray];
}
- (IBAction)addSection:(UIButton *)sender {

[self addSectionArray];
[self.tableViewTest reloadData];
}

- (void) addSectionArray{

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Height",@"label", @"", @"value", nil];
NSArray *arraysection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict, nil];

[self.arrayData addObject:arraysection];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableViewTest.frame.size.width, 45)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
return view;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

// Return the number of sections.
return [self.arrayData count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [[self.arrayData objectAtIndex:section] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellDetails" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *arraysection = [self.arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSDictionary *dict = [arraysection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"label"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"value"];
return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: like below answer, In addSection, you can use insertSections method and reload only the new section rather than reload the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Just have a property (e.g. `numberOfSections`)
- Set it to `1` in `viewDidLoad`
- In the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` `return self.numberOfSections;`
- In the IBAction of your `UIButton` add this code:

```
self.numberOfSections++;
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:self.numberOfSections-1]
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```